# Arithmetic mean 6 times greater than GCD?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am not sure how to find an answer to this question. Is there a way to solve it without simply trial and error?

Do there exist ten distinct positive integers such that their arithmetic mean is

(a) six times as great as their greatest common divisor?

(b) five times as great as their greatest common divisor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us call the ten positive integers $a_1 , a_2 , \dots , a_{10}$ and let us call their GCD $d$. Note that $d \mid a_i$ for each $i$. We can write $a_i = b_i d $ with $b_i$ a positive integer.

The condition for a) is:
$$\frac{a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_{10}}{10} =  6  d$$

Let us divide by $d$ to get:

$$\frac{b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_{10}}{10} =  6  $$

So  the question turns into are their $10$ distinct positive *integers*,  $b_i$ such that their arithmetic mean is $6$, equivalently 
$$b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_{10} =  60  $$
are their $10$ distinct positive  *integers*  $b_i$ such that their sum is $60$. (To be precise we should also say  whose GCD is $1$ but this is a detail).

Recall that  the sum of the *first* $10$ positive integers is already $1+ 2 + \dots + 10 = 55$. So let us start $b_1 = 1, b_2 = 2, \dots, b_9 = 9$ and then $b_10= 15$.
You can now choose $d$ to be whatever you like and multiply $b_i$ by it to get the $a_i$.
If you want to make it simple just take $d=1$ and you are done.

For b) it would be that the sum must be $50$. This is not possible.

Comment: I don't understand the part where you say "So you are looking..."  Could you please further explain. Thank you.

Comment: The quantity can be written as $\frac{a_1}{d}+ \frac{a_2}{d} + \dots$; call $\frac{a_i}{d}= b_i$. So you need $b_1 + \dots + b_{10}= 60$. The $b_i$ are all integers as the $d$ divides the $a_i$ being the GCD.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I am still really confused. Could you please try and explain how to find the answer to this question more simply. I really appreciate your support.

Comment: I expanded the answer a bit; if it is still unclear please be specific what is unclear. Or what is the first thing that is unclear.

Comment: For part (a) would 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,11,12 be correct?

Comment: Yes that would work too.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: If d were 2 would part be be possible. Does it make a difference if you define d as any other number other than 1?

Comment: No, part b is never possible. The value of $d$ is not important at all. You see it cancels out of the condition. Note that from you solution you get a solution for any $d$ you want; just multiply everything by $d$, so $d,2d, 3d, 4d,5d, 6d, 7d, 9d, 11d, 12d$.